# how do i parse json file using python

Tags: python, json

After doing a rest api call and storing result as json file contents of json file look as follows:

["x","y","z"]

I need to use python script to iterate through each item and print it out.

I have the following snippet of code which does error out.

```html
with open('%s/staging_area/get_label.json' % cwd) as data_file:
  data = json.load(data_file)
for item in data:
 print data [item]
```

Error I am getting is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 8.py", line 33, in <module>
    print data [item]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

What am I missing?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: `for item in data: print item`

Comment: You’re parsing the JSON file perfectly; you’re just not using the list right. Either `for item in data: print item` or `for index in range(len(data)): print data[index]`. (Hopefully it’s obvious why the first one is better.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
for item in data:
```

you set `item` to be an element of `data`, but then in the line

```
print data [item]
```

you use `item` as an index, which it is not. Hence the error. There is also no need to use an index since `item` is already an element of `data`.

What you can do instead is:

```
for item in data:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation.  That worked!  much appreciated!